# Gets не дает ничего ввести

Tags: ruby

Пытаюсь написать простенький парсер xls файлов на руби. Хочу, чтобы человек мог ввести нужные ему адреса ячеек, данные из которых ему необходимы.
Использую гем [roo](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo)

Файл открывается, всё хорошо, но когда хочу сделать простое считывание ввода с клавиатуры, работа прекращается и программа работает дальше.

```
require "roo"
require "roo-xls"

class Parser

  def initialize(filename)
    @file_path = File.path(filename)
    @colmn_names = []
  end

  def open_xls
    @xls = Roo::Excel.new(@file_path)
    @xls.default_sheet = @xls.sheets.first
  end

  def pars_column_names
    @xls.last_column.times do |i|
      next if @xls.cell(1, i).nil? and @xls.cell(2, i).nil?
      if @xls.cell(1, i).nil?
        @colmn_names << @xls.cell(2, i)
        next
      end
      @colmn_names << @xls.cell(1, i)
    end
  end

  def ask_cells
    puts "Enter column names that you want to parse"
    cols = gets
  end

  def main
    ask_cells
    open_xls
    pars_column_names
    p @colmn_names
  end
end

parser = Parser.new(ARGV[0])
parser.main
```

Метод `ask_cell` просто выводит строку, ждет пару секунд и завершается. Программа доходит до конца и выводит массив. Почему `gets` так себя ведет?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблему можно исправить двумя способами:

```
parser = Parser.new(ARGV.shift)
```

или

```
  def ask_cells
    puts "Enter column names that you want to parse"
    cols = $stdin.gets
  end
```

Вот [тут](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/185266) есть объяснение:

> Kernel#gets reads from ARGF, which, if there's anything in ARGV, is
>   read from those files. So you can clear from ARGV first, if you want
>   the option of passing your file as the 3rd arg instead of stdin.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, помогло.